# In xterm, how do I disable Alt-<SPACE> from giving me the window menu?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, xterm

I am using emacs -nw in xterm, and when i want to use the emacs shortcut M- to collapse whitespace to a single space it triggers the menu with the minimize, maximize, resize etc.. options of the xterm window. How can I disable that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window menu is not a feature of the termimal emulator, but of the window manager (or desktop environment). As [this forum answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12191235&postcount=6) explains, to disable it in Unity, you have to change the HUD-activation key to something other than Alt, *and* deactivate the window menu binding. Both settings are found under System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.